# Is there a way to set an ASP.Net hidden field value to NULL using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, null, hidden-field

I'm looking at tons of examples of how to set a hidden field value using Javascript.  My question is actually, can you set a hidden field value to NULL using Javascript / jquery, then have that NULL reflected in the value on serverside?

Every time I try and set null, I get back blank.

I have a specific requirement to know the difference between NULL and blank, and the only allowed mode of communication between client a server is a runat=server hidden field.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Null is something that is only related to Database, JavaScript and front end should treat NULL as nothing. I suggest you change your approach and use some enums

Answer (score 0):

I can think one way to make it null, totally remove the `value` attribute, or even harder remove the `name` attribute so it will not post back, and then add it back when this input have again value.

Or set to that value a parameter like 'null' and check for that on code behind.

Think, that the `null` is one more parameter on your list, nothing more nothing less, and the values that are post back are all actually strings. So the only conflict that you can have is you set it "null" is in case that you have a text, but on text you can compare with no text at all and decide if this can be null or empty... is decisions that you must make.